# Job bookmark not working properly in step function level

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am facing an issue related to job bookmark(enable/disable/pause) in step function.

## Scenario

I have a glue job name **"myjob1"** with having configuration enabled job bookmark by manually/selecting from drop down in job details.

Now my case is I want to run single glue job multiple times by passing different parameters via step function.

Here I am able to run parallelly multiple tables but in this case job bookmark is not working properly and creating duplicates at s3 output.

## Approaches Tried

1.Bookmark working successfully in glue job when passed from drop down in job detail section.
2.Bookmark is not working when passed from parameter(--job-bookmark-option:job-bookmark-enable).
3.Bookmark is not working when one glue job is run from step function and bookmark is enabled from drop down in job detail section.

Any suggestion/solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Bookmark functionality (enable/disable/pause) with step function should work for my concurrent running same glue job.